# scanf each digit of integer AND store the whole number in C

Tags: c, input, printf, scanf

Example input: 12345

As you can see I can store each digit "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" through scanf but how do I store the whole number "12345"? Can it happen within the same scanf line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){

    int wholeNumber = 0;
    int i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 = 0;

    printf("\nPlease enter a five digit integer value.\n");
    scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d",&i,&i2,&i3,&i4,&i5); //scanning each digit but 
                                                 //how do I store the whole #?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not within one line.  You could read the line with `fgets()` and then parse it twice with `sscanf()` to get first the separate digits and then the whole number (or vice versa).  But that's two passes over the data.  What should happen if there are 4 or 6 digits in the input stream?  Note that the `"%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d"` format will be happy with `1 2 3 4 5` as well as `12345` (and `12 3 45`).

Comment: It's isn't clear why you are not just reading the complete number, but that's up to you. If you must read each digit, then you can simply loop `getchar()` and subtracting `'0'` (ASCII zero) from each to get the integer value. Then you can sew them together by multiplying with increasing powers of `10` mindful of the maximum value that can be stored in your final type (e.g. `int`, `long`, etc...).

Comment: Using variables named `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`, `i5` cries out for the use of an array, which will be vastly more flexible in the long run.  Coding with those five fixed names will be painful and repetitive.  You could also simply read a number once and then break it into the digits array when you've got the value.  Are leading zeros allowed?  They complicate things if breaking the value into the array.  The alternative is to read into the array in a loop.  The array can handle more or less digits more easily than the fixed set of 5 variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer your first question. You can simply multiply the entered numbers by multiples of 10. Lets show it with calculation:

5*1 + 4*10 + 3*100 + 2*1000 + 1*10000 = 12345

So, here is the code for a manual use:

```
...
scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d",&i,&i2,&i3,&i4,&i5);
i*=10000;
i2*=1000;
i3*=100;
i4*=10;
i5*=1;
...
```

Comment: Good solution, but not generic. This algorithm can represent numbers from 0 to 99999. @William Toscano didn't actually outline any limits for the input number though.

Comment: @AlexanderPane: In fairness, the code does say: `"Please enter a five digit integer value"`.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Didn't see it :)